# Can't add cookie anymore in request.jar

Tags: node.js, cookies, request

I use request.js in a project, and since the version 2.30.0, I can't do that anymore:

```
var j = request.jar();
var cookie = request.cookie('uid');
cookie.value = browser.cookies.select({name:'uid'})[0].value;
j.add(cookie);
```

My error is:

```
 TypeError: Object #<CookieJar> has no method 'add'
```

Someone had the problem and solved it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Gotcha!

Since request uses tough-cookie (https://github.com/goinstant/node-cookie), we can add cookies like that:

```
j.setCookie(cookie, 'http://currentdomain.example.com/path', function(error, cookie) {});
```

Comment: Thanks nicolas, I've been looking for this for hours!